# Hiding Safari User Interface Components on iPhone

Tags: safari, iphone, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

In an attempt to hide the Safari UI components for an web-app bookmarked as a Homescreen Icon. I am using this meta tag

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

as specified on [iPhone Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2) but the address bar and toolbar are still there when launched from the home screen icon.  What do I need to do different? Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 30):

```
window.top.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

Works on iPhone, but not in iPad.  I have been successful hiding the browser components on iPad (so presumably everywhere) by using

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

and launching from a home-screen link.  I am also using

```
<meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I have not tried seeing if the browser components are still hidden if I leave out the viewport properties.

Comment: The first option is the only thing that worked for me. I added <body onload="window.top.scrollTo(0,1);"> And it worked. All the other options weren't working for me at all.

Comment: same here, scrollTo(0,1) makes the address bar go away, but the meta tags appear to have no impact on it.

Comment: An important note on `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`, if you already have the application bookmarked, delete the bookmark and re-add to enable the change.

Comment: Is there any other way, instead of 'launching from a home-screen link' to make it work on iPad?

Answer (score 7):

Is it being launched from the home screen? The documentation on the linked page does not mention but I found this @ [Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/webapps/docs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/chapter_8_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3):

> For example, you can specify an icon for your web application used to represent it when added to the Home screen, as described in “Specifying a Webpage Icon for Web Clip.” **You can also minimize the Safari on iPhone user interface**, as described in “Changing the Status Bar Appearance” and “Hiding Safari User Interface Components,” **when your web application is launched from the Home screen**. These are all optional settings that when added to your web content are ignored by other platforms

Comment: Here's the updated link: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: Spot on crashmstr. The meta tags only work... WHEN THE APP IS LAUNCHED FROM THE HOME SCREEN.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding...

```
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
```

Comment: this is undocumented. probably not used in stable releases of Mobile Safari.

Comment: Indeed, cannot find a reference for this anymore (wrote in 2010). Looks like only `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` is advised today (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html))

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, iOS only pays attention to the flags when you actually add the app.  If the apple-mobile-web-app-capable thingy doesn't work at first, try deleting your app from the home screen then re-adding it.

I've run some experiments and found:

- the location of the meta tag within the headers doesn't seem to matter (I thought it might!)
- after adding the app and having it remove the address bar correctly, if you then remove the meta tags from the web page, iOS continues to remove the toolbar.
- even after rebooting the device it still 'remembers' whether to remove the toolbar.  The only way I've found of resetting this behaviour is to remove and re-add the app.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old, but I came across this while searching for a solution. I was able to fix this by also adding:

```
window.top.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

to the body's onload method. Hope it helps anyone else coming across this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new directive, called "minimal-ui" that iOS browser takes into account (at least on the iPhone where I tested). Toolbars are hidden until the user clicks on the status bar on top. Very nice for one page apps!

Here is the snippet I use:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">`

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2

It works on iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 7.1, you can use `minimal-ui`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui">
```

Answer (score 0):

That should indeed behave as expected, I have used it in the past without any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This will work if:

1. The tag exists when the app is added to the home screen.
2. The app is launched from the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

works on iOS6 + Mobile Safari Browser but ONLY if you added the page to your homescreen AFTER you included the meta tag on your site.

Answer (score 0):

all above meta tags and window.scrollTo, did not work on ipad for me,
i found a button on safari next to bookmarks where you get an option called 'Add  to Home Screen' it creates a new tile icon, and you can launch your web app like a native app, and no address bar there.